# Doubt in documentation job

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My pull request for indigo,melodic and lunar were merged two days ago for addition in documentation index. Melodic and indigo documentation appears on ROS Wiki but lunar does not appear.

http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_keyboard_omni3

I also checked the doc job and it shows no build.
http://build.ros.org/job/Ldoc__teleop_keyboard_omni3__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/

The devel job was built 2days ago.
http://build.ros.org/job/Ldev__teleop_keyboard_omni3__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/

Do I need to do something or is something wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318168/doubt-in-documentation-job/) by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My pull request for indigo,melodic and lunar were merged two days ago for addition in documentation index.

From what I can tell, everything should be fine. The `doc` entries for Lunar in `distribution.yaml` look ok.

As I wrote in #q317691, doc jobs are run once every three days, so it could be that yours is waiting to be run, or we're just at the end of the three day period.

Your enthusiasm is great to see, but I'd suggest to wait a little longer.

> Melodic and indigo documentation appears on ROS Wiki but lunar does not appear.

Note: all jobs on the buildfarm are independent, in the sense that there are separate jobs for the documentation generation for the Indigo, Kinetic and Lunar versions of your package. The fact that some have been run already while others haven't doesn't necessarily point to something being wrong.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on 2019-03-11**:
Thanks for the reply !

**Comment by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on 2019-03-11**:
Is there a way to know which package is currently running in the buildfarm. Also do the packages run alphabetically ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-11**:
Please do not ask follow-up questions in comments under (previously) accepted answers.

Comments have very limited visibility, and in addition ROS Answers works best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions and answers. This is not a regular forum.